# `std::is_same_v<size_t, uint64_t>` evaluates to `false` when both types are 8 bytes long

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, language-lawyer, sizeof

Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main() {
  std::cout << "sizeof(size_t): " << sizeof(size_t) << std::endl;
  std::cout << "sizeof(uint64_t): " << sizeof(uint64_t) << std::endl;
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<size_t, uint64_t>) {
    std::cout << "size_t == uint64_t" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "size_t != uint64_t" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Result:

```
sizeof(size_t): 8
sizeof(uint64_t): 8
size_t != uint64_t
```

Compiler Info:

```
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
Target: arm64-apple-darwin21.6.0
Thread model: posix
```

Is there a reason why `size_t` doesn't equal `uint64_t`? If so, is there a particular mention in the standard of why this is so?

Comment: On all modern platforms I know, two of the three have the same size: `int`, `long`, `long long`, while all three are always distinct types. For you, either `size_t` is `unsigned long` and `uint64_t` is `unsigned long long`, or the other way around.

Comment: [I'm getting `size_t == uint64_t` on gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/1c1W5cE8z)

Comment: I had always assumed that `size_t` was typedef'd to some unsigned int type. Does the standard specify that `size_t` must be treated as a completely different type?

Comment: [Also on clang](https://godbolt.org/z/oGqsj8av4).

Comment: @segfault I'm not sure if that's specified in the standard, but I'd expect it to be typedefed to a builtin type.

Comment: Try `std::is_same_v<size_t, unsigned long>` and `std::is_same_v<size_t, unsigned long long>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually the type `size_t` is an alias for the type `unsigned long`.

From the C Standard (7.19 Common definitions <stddef.h>)

> 4 **The types used for size_t and ptrdiff_t should not have an integer
> conversion rank greater than that of signed long int** unless the
> implementation supports objects large enough to make this necessary.

Pay attention to that the rank of the type `unsigned long int` is equal to the rank of the type `signed long int`.

On the other hand, the type `uint64_t` usually is defined as an alias for the type `unsigned long long int`. Though that is  implementation defined.

As for your code then the shown output means that `sizeof( unsigned long int )` also is equal to 8 on the used system.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if I am trying to handle all possible unsigned integer inputs in a templated function, it's not sufficient to add cases for {`uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`, `uint64_t`} since an implementation might use some weird number like 36 bytes?

Answer (score 0):

> 3. The type size_­t is an implementation-defined unsigned integer type that is large enough to contain the size in bytes of any object ([expr.sizeof]).
> 4. Recommended practice: An implementation should choose types for ptrdiff_­t and size_­t whose integer conversion ranks ([conv.rank]) are no greater than that of signed long int unless a larger size is necessary to contain all the possible values.

[[support.types]](https://eel.is/c++draft/support.types#layout-3)